# Cannot access value of resolved promise after array of Promise.all

Tags: javascript

Cannot access value of resolved promise after `Promise.all`. As you see in the example below, `res.prop` prints undefined. I guess I could create a wrapping function that pushes the resolved value to another `responses` array but that does not seem like a clean way to do it.

```
(async () => {
    const responses = []

    let counter = 10
    while (counter--) {
      responses.push(new Promise(resolve => resolve({prop: 10})))
    }

    await Promise.all(responses)

    for (const res of responses) {
        console.log(res) // -> prints Promise {prop: 10}
        console.log(res.prop) // -> prints undefined
    }
})()
```

Comment: You never use the return value of `await Promise.all(responses)`. The return value of your promises is returned by `Promises.all` Edit : posted as answer for easier testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never use the return value of `await Promise.all(responses)`. The return value of your promises is returned by `Promises.all` :

```js
(async () => {
    const responses = []

    let counter = 10
    while (counter--) {
      responses.push(new Promise(resolve => resolve({prop: 10})))
    }

    const results = await Promise.all(responses)

    for (const res of results) {
        console.log(res) // -> prints Promise {prop: 10}
        console.log(res.prop) // -> prints undefined
    }
})()
```